# clicking chain on 3rd gear only

Tags: shimano, chain, derailleur-rear

Shimano DI2 11 speed XTR on my gravel bike. The 3rd from smallest gear on the cassette makes a clicking sound.  Any other gear its fine.  Cassette and chain are fairly new.  Have reindexed, checked the hanger with my new park tool hanger checker, and checked the chain with park cc4.  All of that is fine. I think the click is coming from the chain exiting the cassette.  I replaced all this and have done less than 300 miles on the bike since I replaced the chain and cassette. I am meticulous about keeping all the gears in the cassette in order, I put a twisty through the whole assembly any time I remove it so that everything stays in the correct order - A spacing problem seems most likely, but as I say, very careful about that.  I have a video of it but its like 63 Meg and I don't have anywhere currently I can upload and share a link and its a bit clumsy as I had to hold the phone and stop pedaling with my hand to change the gears... but anyway, you can hear the click on just the 3rd gear - what's a good way to include a video here? I'm new to the bike stack and have never had to upload videos to stack exchange before.  Thanks
Bill

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  You might be able to upload your video to imgur and include the link here.